# How to split binding string ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6-classic

How can I split string and get length if she bind?
I tried this, but displayed value is empty:

```
{
        xtype: 'displayfield',
        fieldLabel: __('sending_to'),
        bind: {
            value: '{recipients.split("\n").length}'
        }
}
```

Comment: No I'm not tried literals because sencha cmd can not parse that syntax.
Recipients it's string witch holds e-mail addresses witch separated \n.
Binded value I mean that it dynamically changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [formulas](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.app.ViewModel.html#cfg-formulas) to put more logic in it. And about your question, here's the [**FIDDLE**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2l9j)